# Difference between "going to" and "not going to"

Tags: infinitives, imperative-sentences

I wonder what is the difference between going to and not going to in the following sentences:

- We're going to play football in my garden.
- you're not going to play football in my garden.

Comment: It seems to me that the more important differences is between *we* and *you*.

Comment: We and you are not to be neglected

Comment: Are you expecting the answer that the second sentence sounds like a ban rather than a simple statement of fact? As Peter says, it's the change of subject that makes the difference. What about _We're not going to play football in my garden, we're going to play in the park_?

Comment: Beg your pardon, it's not only the change of subject that makes the difference.

Comment: Well, in that case why did you use a different subject in your example? You tell us what you think the difference is.

Comment: @wuqt: To see that the change of subject is actually what makes the difference, consider *I'm going to do the washing up* and *You're going to do the washing up.*

Comment: @Peter Shor: What About This Sentence? You/we are going to finish that soup whether you/we like it or not!

Comment: "if anyone doubts of the difference between a thing that is and a thing that is not, he should be beaten until he admits that there is a difference between being beaten and not being beaten." -Avicenna

Answer (score 1):

"going to" and "not going to" can be used in multiple ways.

They can be used to make predictions, as in

> It's going to rain tonight.
>   It's not going to rain tonight.

But if the speaker is a person in authority, this prediction is often used to express an imperative. For instance, a parent might say to their child

> You're going to be home by 9pm.
>   You're not going to the party.

As you can see, these forms can be used in both the positive and negative forms. The distinction is usually determined from context. Tone of voice can also be used -- the parent would say these with a stern voice.

In your examples, the first sentence is a prediction (it would be unusual to express an imperative in the first person), the second is usually an imperative. But it would be easy to change the second sentence to a prediction:

> You're not going to play football in my garden, since the gate is locked.